# How to destroy cache image when change the picture

Tags: image, codeigniter, caching

I have a home page where there is an image slider.  every day the picture must be changed.  I think by changing the image with the same name it will be easier every day but when I have finished changing the image I have to press ctrl + f5 first.

How to solved this problem? This is caching problem?

I use codeigniter

Comment: Hi, yes it sounds like the image is being cached. You can check the cache settings by inspecting the response headers for the image request.

Comment: *Please refer this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135826/348234) to learn about accepting answer. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Generating the image URL add `base_url($image_path)."?t=".date("Ymd");`
This will request the server a fresh image daily.

Comment: I do essentially the same thing `img.jpg?<?php echo time(); ?>`

Comment: When use `time()` it will request a fresh image every time you load the page. Misdan asked to refresh image daily, that's why use `date("Ymd")`

Comment: yea true, i was just saying.